# How can I turn this into a loop with R?

Tags: r, loops

How can I loop this without copy/paste 30 times and changing 1 to 2 (to 3,4,5..etc) in the first and last lines?

Answer (score 1):

The first questions sounds like the goal is to read in multiple datasets at once and then iterate over them with a given set of functions. Look into the 'list.files' function to see all the files in a given directory to help get started. Here is a small example which might help give some ideas to get you on the right track if I understood the main goals correctly:

```
library(tidyverse)

#setup reproducible example
#writes the iris dataframe 3 times to desktop
iris_list <- list(iris, iris, iris)
num <- c(1, 2, 3)
filenames <- paste0("~/Desktop/iris", num, ".csv")
purrr::map2(iris_list, filenames, write.csv)


#list.files returns a character vector of all the files in a given directory 
#see ?list.files for more info
iris_files <- list.files("~/Desktop", pattern = "iris", full.names = TRUE)

#with a loop
read_iris_loop <- list()
for(i in seq_along(iris_files)){
  read_iris_loop[[i]] <- read.csv(iris_files[[i]])
}
#or with map/lapply
read_iris <- purrr::map(iris_files, read.csv)

#loop/map over datasets with your functions using these as a template
```

Answer (score 1):

First create a vector with the files names:

```
library(tidyverse)
files_vector <- map_chr(1:30, ~paste0(.x,".sch"))
```

Make sure the files are inside the working directory, then use the following code to create a list with all the files in it.

```
files_list <- map(files_vector, ~ read.csv)
```

Then convert your actually working code in a custom function and iterate it over the files_list using:

```
map(files_list, ~ custom_function(.x))
```

If you need you can send parameters to your custom function:

```
map(files_list, ~ custom_function(.x), ...)
```

I would also recommend this awesome talk about map functions and the purrr package at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7UlWJWfZO9M